# Android ListView Row has a frame

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

This XML is for a ROW in a custom listview. It seems to have an Invisible FRAME, I can't seem to be able  to get rid of it and make row fill parent.
I would like the end result to be nothing but Rows, and not able to see background of layer below.

Thank you for reading, XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#ff515152"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#fffff7fd"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#fffff7fd"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="AND"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/group_name"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#fffff7fd"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffb7bcb5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="#fffff7fd" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="#fffff7fd" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you link to a image of what you are getting? Also, just an fyi `RelativeLayout` doesn't have an `orientation` property

Comment: Padding attribute in root `RelativeLayout`? This is maybe your "frame".